# Joining a third table with directly with the first or via an intermediary

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, left-join

I'm trying to join 3 tables, where the third table contains a reference to the second and to the first; and I want the result for either of these references.  However where the third table references the first, I don't need the result from the second.

It's hard to explain, so I've illustrated what I'm after with the below example.

The first select statement produces 6 rows; I understand why, but that's not what I'm after.

The second 2 give the result that I'm after, but there's a code smell to them.  Can anyone advise of a better approach for achieving the same output?

See also SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8029cc/1

```
--code to setup my example

    declare @t1 table (id bigint, val nvarchar(10))
    declare @t2 table (id bigint, t1Id bigint, val2 nvarchar(10))
    declare @t3 table (id bigint, t1Id bigint, t2Id bigint, val3 nvarchar(10))

    insert @t1 (id, val) values (1, '1.1')

    insert @t2 (id, t1Id, val2) 
    values (1, 1, '2.1')
    ,(2, 1, '2.2')
    ,(3, 1, '2.3')

    insert @t3 (id, t1Id, t2Id, val3) 
    values (1, 1, null, 'XXX')
    , (1, null, 1, '3.1')
    ,(2, null, 2, '3.2')
    ,(3, null, 3, '3.3')
```

.

```
--this produces 6 results; I only want 4

    select *
    from @t1 t1
    left outer join @t2 t2 
        on t2.t1Id = t1.Id
    left outer join @t3 t3
        on t3.t2Id = t2.Id
        or t3.t1Id = t1.id
```

.

```
--this works, but means repeating myself; which I'd prefer not to do if possible (could use a cte to make that simpler in the real world scenario, but still not ideal)

    select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t1.val, t2.val2, t3.val3
    from @t1 t1
    left outer join @t2 t2 
        on t2.t1Id = t1.Id
    left outer join @t3 t3
        on t3.t2Id = t2.Id

    union all

    select t1.id, null, t3.id, t1.val, null, t3.val3
    from @t1 t1
    left outer join @t3 t3
        on t3.t1Id = t1.id
```

.

```
--this works too, but feels very hacky

    select t1.id, t2.id, t3.id, t1.val, t2.val2, t3.val3
    from @t1 t1
    left outer join 
    (
        select id, t1id, val2
        from @t2

        union all

        select null, null, null

    ) t2 
        on coalesce(t2.t1Id,t1.Id) = t1.Id
    left outer join @t3 t3
        on t3.t2Id = t2.Id
        or (t3.t1Id = t1.id and t2.Id is null)
```

---

**Update**

I just thought of another solution which feels a little cleaner than those above; though I'm still a little uncomfortable with it...

```
--another option; again slightly hacky

    select id, id2, id3, val, val2, val3
    from
    (
        select t1.id
        , case when t3.t1Id = t1.id then null else t2.id end id2
        , t3.id id3
        , t1.val
        , case when t3.t1Id = t1.id then null else t2.val2 end val2
        , t3.val3
        , row_number() over (partition by t1.id order by case when t3.t1Id = t1.id then null else t2.id end, t3.id) x
        from @t1 t1
        left outer join @t2 t2 
            on t2.t1Id = t1.Id
        left outer join @t3 t3
            on t3.t2Id = t2.Id
            or t3.t1Id = t1.id
    ) t
    where id2 is not null or x = 1
```

Comment: ps. for anyone using the above to find a solution to their issue, I've found that in most realistic scenarios the first working solution above (i.e. `union all` between the result of `t1 join t2 join t3` and `t1 join t3`) is the most efficient.

Comment: Update: most answers to date have suggested moving t3 to the FROM.  If I add a new value to my test date; `insert @t1 (id, val) values (1, '1.1'), (8, '8.1')` you'll see an issue with this approach; i.e. we no longer have every value from t1.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didn't fully understand your requirement/output.

However, the query should have same result

```
SELECT *
FROM t3 
LEFT JOIN t2 
  ON t2.id = t3.t2Id
LEFT JOIN t1
  ON t3.t1Id = t1.id
  AND t2.id IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

try this query, it will produce same output result as in your last query:

```
SELECT T.ID, 
       CASE WHEN T3.t2Id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE  T.T2ID END AS T2ID,
       T3.id AS T3ID,
       T.VAL, 
       CASE WHEN T3.t2Id IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE  T.VAL2 END AS VAL2,
       T3.VAL3
FROM (SELECT T1.id, 
             T1.val,
             T2.Id AS T2ID, 
             T2.val2
      FROM @t1 AS T1 JOIN @t2 AS T2 
                  ON T1.id = T2.t1id
      ) AS T JOIN @t3 AS T3 
           ON T.T2ID = T3.ID
ORDER BY  T3.VAL3
```

**[test is here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/395625)**

output result

[image]

Answer (score 1):

pretty simple - your mistake is your starting table.
Start with Table 3 and left join to the others - then add a where condition.
I.e.

```
    SELECT * FROM  @t3
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @t1
    ON [@t1].id = [@t3].t1id
    LEFT OUTER JOIN @t2
    ON [@t2].id = [@t3].t2id
    WHERE [@t1].id IS NOT NULL
    OR ( [@t2].id IS NOT NULL AND [@t1].id IS NULL)
```

Comment: did you test your query?